# Dictionary webservice recommendation

Tags: web-services

Lot of googling did not help me! Are there any good dictionary web based available?

I am looking for a site which can send me the meaning of words if we pass the word through query string!

Comment: *dictionary

Please proofread your posts before posting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found you a [Big Huge Thesaurus](http://words.bighugelabs.com/) with a web API, and a dictionary at [Aonaware](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/) that looks like it uses SOAP

Comment: Thank you very much Jacob and stackoverflow!! That was very helpful

Comment: No problem, shoban :)
If you wouldn't mind, you could choose this as the "accepted answer" so it turns green.

Comment: Is there any web service other than Aonaware for XML format as this service is currently not available?

Answer (score 4):

There also exists the [dict](http://dict.org) protocol which has been around for a long time. One of the things I like about dict is the command-line query program that is available.

I have also created a [Wiktionary to dict gateway](http://hewgill.com/dict/) which provides access to the Wiktionary database through the dict protocol.

Answer (score 3):

I found another three:

- Programmable Web: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/oxford-english-dictionary
- Glosbe API: http://glosbe.com/a-api
- DictService: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx

Comment: Is there any web service other than Aonaware for XML format as this service is currently not available?