# Java word game query

Tags: java, validation, cpu-word, implementation

Im coding a small app more or less like a word game.
There is a requirement to validate a word that the user may create to check if it is a valid english word or not.
I have thought of some ways to implement this --
1) Have a hashmap with every english word as a key and a boolean as value. this way i could search for the key at the time of user validation ans so on. 
2) Send a HTTP request to some site like dictionary.com to verify if the word exists or not.

Though HTTP request seems to me like a nice way to get this implemented, I wanted to have a hashmap which is at first is filled in and then at periodic intervals updated from a source, say dictionary.com so that I could avoid the latencies involved in the HTTP request implementation.

Any pointers on how I could fill in the hashmap with the words from the source would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
p1nG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web services and Big Huge Thesaurus. It's a REST Web services, so you might need tools like Jersey, or RestEasy.

An alternative would be Oanaware and its SOAP web service.

---

**Resources :**

- [Big Hughe Thesaurus](http://words.bighugelabs.com/)
- [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)
- [RestEasy](http://jboss.org/resteasy)
- [Oanaware](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx)
- [IBM.com - Invoking web services with Java clients](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-javaclient/index.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Dictionary webservice recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257/dictionary-webservice-recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think checking a hash of a word would be enough. Two words might have same hash. Moreover, random sequence of letters can have same hash value as a correct word. Taking in account these two points, I do not think you will be able to avoid checking your word (looking it up in a dictionary).

I am not sure what would be a best way to fill up your dictionary. Try to find free dictionary software and check what their license says about the data they use. I think it would be easier to buy something like [this](http://www.openwall.com/wordlists/).

If that is not an option, online processing is not a bad option I think.

Comment: From what I understood, when a collection has a collision with 2 or more entries with the same hash key it iterates over each one checking the plaintext key for a match. So I would guess that the plaintext key stored with the collection is checked too. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: That is correct.  If there is a hash collisions it will be resolved by using the equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

How about downloading a list of words. You could use WordNet http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/ a list of 155,287 words with synonyms and much more.

Or google for something like "list of english words" lots of relevant links on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check if a word exists in the dictionary, why not use a HashSet? You can use a plaintext dictionary file with a word on each line, or at least that is what I have done in the past.

Not sure about updating it, but if dictionary.com provides a file with with wordlistings you can just download that, then open the file and add every entry to you hash map/set. Assuming no words would be removed, existing entries would just be overwritten.

Edit: Just wrote a test prog that should demonstrate collisions would not be a problem with a hashmap or hash set when checking your word.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CollidingHash {
    String value;
    public CollidingHash(String s){
        value=s;
    }
    @Override 
    public int hashCode(){
        return 1;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(! (o instanceof CollidingHash)){
            return false;
        }
        CollidingHash c2 = (CollidingHash)o;
        return value.equals(c2.value);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<CollidingHash> dict = new HashSet<CollidingHash>();
        CollidingHash a = new CollidingHash("This");
        CollidingHash b = new CollidingHash("That");
        dict.add(a);
        System.out.println("Is "+ (dict.contains(b)? "Bad": "OK"));
    }   
}
```

Edit2: added equals method as Pace mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Have a hashmap with every english
>   word as a key and a boolean as value.
>   this way i could search for the key at
>   the time of user validation ans so on.

A `HashMap` is overkill for this task.  You just need to know whether a word exists, so you could use a `HashSet`.  After adding all the words to the `HashSet`, you would use the `contains()` method to check to see whether a word exists in the `HashSet` or not.  But you must be aware that this is a case-sensitive approach, so you would have to make sure that all your words have the same case (for example, "hello" will not match "Hello").

Also, I don't know how memory-intensive loading the entire English dictionary into memory would be.  If you run into problems, a better approach might be to scan the dictionary file every time you need to check if a word exists.

> 2) Send a HTTP request to some site
>   like dictionary.com to verify if the
>   word exists or not.

This would work too, but it relies on (1) the computer having an active Internet connection and (2) the dictionary.com website being up.