# Is there a possibility of writing an application that uses the vocabulary of a page in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create applications in Java (in a desktop JavaFX) that will use the dictionary (translation of words) on some website? That is, for example, collects a. All translations for the word. Google provides a library using the translator, but I wonder if you can try to create something to download from other sites. Perhaps it is an interesting task for PHP but I'm learning Java and how it already in this language I would like to create. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** question:

Can someone determine what to read or where to learn something about this?

Comment: Possible?  Of course.  Though I think answer to the issue may be way beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: And that could do the trick there any tips? What to focus on this topic

Comment: Could you explain why this should be better suited for PHP than Java?

Comment: It seems to me that PHP is more suitable for processing data of the parties. But I can be wrong because I ask how it looks.

Comment: Here are some Dictionary Webservice Recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257/dictionary-webservice-recommendation